# FB SDK and cURL: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to graph.facebook.com:443

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl, ssl

Using FaceBook SDK (fetched today) I am getting error

`Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 35: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to graph.facebook.com:443 
  thrown in /var/www/clients/client18/web29/web/classDBI/base_facebook.php on line 996`

I have gone over a dozen related posts and implemented all recommended changes without success.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234140/curl-error-35-unknown-ssl-protocol-error-in-connection) suggests it may clear up on it's own?

Current cURL opts are below and situation persists even if I take unadvised measure of adding

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => false,
```

Current opts

```
 public static $CURL_OPTS = array(
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 60,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 60,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'facebook-php-3.2',
    CURLOPT_SSLVERSION   => 3,
    CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE => CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4
  );
```

Does anyone have an additional opt or test I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the case of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234140/curl-error-35-unknown-ssl-protocol-error-in-connection) adding `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION   => 3` did not immediately resolve the issue today the SSL has been re-validated and accepted.

Comment: Please someone rectify the sentence structure. I couldn't understand anything.