# cURL Facebook connect: Unknown SSL protocol error

Tags: facebook, ssl, curl, openssl, libcurl

I'm trying to connect to facebook (via wordpress-plugin), Wordpress uses cURL for this.
This worked well until last week, but now I am getting the following error when trying to connect:

```
cURL error 35: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to graph.facebook.com:443
```

To see if it's a wordpress- or cURL-issue i tried this in command line (cURL v7.47.0):

```
curl -v https://graph.facebook.com:443
```

This does not work and gives the following output:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: https://graph.facebook.com:443/
*   Trying 157.240.3.19...
* Connected to graph.facebook.com (157.240.3.19) port 443 (#0)
* found 173 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 695 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function.
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function.
```

When I try the same on my virtual machine (cURL v7.35.0) this works:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: https://graph.facebook.com:443/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 31.13.65.1...
* Connected to graph.facebook.com (31.13.65.1) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* Server certificate:
*        subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Menlo Park; O=Facebook, Inc.; CN=*.facebook.com
*        start date: 2016-12-09 00:00:00 GMT
*        expire date: 2018-01-25 12:00:00 GMT
*        subjectAltName: graph.facebook.com matched
*        issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
*        SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: graph.facebook.com
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< WWW-Authenticate: OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api"
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Pragma: no-cache
< Cache-Control: no-store
< x-fb-rev: 2999583
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
< x-fb-trace-id: HQZT5c74sg/
< facebook-api-version: v2.3
< Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< X-FB-Debug: LV8vPkkNuJL3jABwLClvNFMdS+wAN1ogODJaLY14TjieV3rPXgWaEElPuSqNnQ3mO5qsj2H7OI2xAmlxjevIPA==
< Date: Thu, 04 May 2017 10:11:12 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
<
* Connection #0 to host graph.facebook.com left intact
{"error":{"message":"Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https:\/\/developers.facebook.com\/docs\/graph-api","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"HQZT5c74sg\/"}}
```

I noticed that there's a difference after `Connected to graph.facebook.com (1.2.3.4) port 443 (#0)`.
It worked well until last week (I don't know until which day), but I don't know what I could've changed that it isn't working anymore.

Anybody knows what my problem is?

Edit:
I tried the same with another host (google.com), there it works:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ curl -v https://google.com:443
* Rebuilt URL to: https://google.com:443/
*   Trying 172.217.19.14...
* Connected to google.com (172.217.19.14) port 443 (#0)
* found 173 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 695 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_ECDSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*        server certificate verification OK
*        server certificate status verification SKIPPED
*        common name: *.google.com (matched)
*        server certificate expiration date OK
*        server certificate activation date OK
*        certificate public key: EC
*        certificate version: #3
*        subject: C=US,ST=California,L=Mountain View,O=Google Inc,CN=*.google.com
*        start date: Fri, 21 Apr 2017 08:25:00 GMT
*        expire date: Fri, 14 Jul 2017 08:25:00 GMT
*        issuer: C=US,O=Google Inc,CN=Google Internet Authority G2
*        compression: NULL
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: google.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
< Location: https://www.google.ch/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=gAoLWdqnE-uX8QecpaaIBw
< Content-Length: 259
< Date: Thu, 04 May 2017 11:03:28 GMT
< Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="37,36,35"
<
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.ch/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=gAoLWdqnE-uX8QecpaaIBw">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
* Connection #0 to host google.com left intact
```

Edit 2:
Output of `curl -V`:

```
curl 7.47.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.47.0 GnuTLS/3.4.10 zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.32 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

Comment: curl can be compiled with lots of different options and TLS libraries. Could you please add the output of `curl -V` to your question?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I edited the question. I saw the difference between my systems. The one that does not work uses GnuTLS, the other one uses OpenSSL. How can I change this?

Comment: Do use OpenSSL instead of GnuTLS as the backend for curl you need to have a curl compiled against OpenSSL. It is not possible to just switch the backend in a compiled curl binary.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thanks. Do you know how to do this with Ubuntu 16.04? Or if this really could fix my problem? I didn't find a solution so far.

Comment: I've just tried with 16.04 and there are no problems accessing the site with the same version of curl you use. I suggest that the issue is actually a different one and specific to your system and not curl.  It works for me with all the different IP addresses which can be seen in your debug output. Maybe there is some firewall involved are facebook is blocking your system?

Comment: You're right. The problem was a firewall blocking all requests to facebook ...

Comment: Use TLS 1.0 (or above) and [Server Name Indication (SNI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). Also see [FB SDK and cURL: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to graph.facebook.com:443](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19822075/608639), [How to fix curl sslv3 alert handshake failure?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192944/how-to-fix-curl-sslv3-alert-handshake-failure) on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) and [curl error 35 site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=curl+error+35+site%3Astackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem wasn't cURL or the used SSL library. It was just a firewall blocking requests to facebook.